# Confused by mxnet error for LogisticRegressionOuput

Tags: r, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I am confused by the error I am recieving when running the code below

```
prediction <- predict(model, pred)

     Error in symbol$infer.shape(list(...)) : 
Error in operator logisticregressionoutput0: Shape inconsistent, Provided=
(1,), inferred shape=(1,17)
```

I am running the prediction on a 32,32,1,1 image matrix.  The model was trained for 17 labels for each image.  Why/how do I provide the dimensions for the desired label? Shouldn't it just output a 1x17 vector?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble.
In the end I just used a custom FF based on earlier mxnet version:

```
# these two lines lets us use all the goodies inside mxnet
pkgEnv = getNamespace("mxnet")
attach(pkgEnv)

predict.MXFeedForwardModel <- function(model, X, ctx=NULL, array.batch.size=128, array.layout="auto") {
  if (is.null(ctx)) ctx <- mx.ctx.default()
  if (is.array(X) || is.matrix(X)) {
    if (array.layout == "auto") {
      array.layout <- mx.model.select.layout.predict(X, model)
    }
    if (array.layout == "rowmajor") {
      X <- t(X)
    }
  }
  X <- mx.model.init.iter(X, NULL, batch.size=array.batch.size, is.train=FALSE)
  print('itterSet')
  X$reset()
  if (!X$iter.next()) stop("Cannot predict on empty iterator")
  dlist = X$value()
  pexec <- mx.simple.bind(model$symbol, ctx=ctx, data=dim(dlist$data), grad.req="null")
  mx.exec.update.arg.arrays(pexec, model$arg.params, match.name=TRUE)
  mx.exec.update.aux.arrays(pexec, model$aux.params, match.name=TRUE)
  packer <- mx.nd.arraypacker()
  X$reset()
  while (X$iter.next()) {
    dlist = X$value()
    mx.exec.update.arg.arrays(pexec, list(data=dlist$data), match.name=TRUE)
    mx.exec.forward(pexec, is.train=FALSE)
    out.pred <- mx.nd.copyto(pexec$ref.outputs[[1]], mx.cpu())
    padded <- X$num.pad()
    oshape <- dim(out.pred)
    ndim <- length(oshape)
    packer$push(mx.nd.slice(out.pred, 0, oshape[[ndim]] - padded))
  }
  X$reset()
  return(packer$get())
}
```